# Gets points from Vector3D and two lines from this point

Tags: c#, math, vector-graphics

I would like to get points between two lines, defined by a Vec3D point for origin, and angle from direction line. Since my english and my Maths are not good enough to explain, i drawn a picture :

[image]

In green valids points, in red not valids.
Someone can help me with this problem ?
I have Vector3D point, and direction (or angle), and the Vec3D list of point to check.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to constrain the angle between center point, checked point and the direction by the half angle:

```
normalize direction
minDotProduct = cos(angle / 2)
for each point p
    d := p - center
    normalize d
    point is valid iff dot(d, direction) >= minDotProduct
next
```